# In the PID equation K[((s+a)^2)/s] what values correspond to the PID coefficients Kp, Ki, Kd?

Tags: control, pid, tuning

I'm trying to understand how to obtain the Kp, Ki, Kd values after finding a combination of K and a that works for me. Do I just expand the equation and take the coefficients?

Comment: I just expanded the equation. I found that Kp=2Ka, Ki=K(a^2) and Kd=K

Comment: Yes, your expansion appears to be correct. But the equation form you mentioned will not be able to create every PID because you only have two variables.

Comment: Then, if your aim is to realize this PID in the SW, good luck :). The formula in the title is **not causal**.

Why don't you rephrase the title and the question so that the question does not assume that the problem is stated **only** in the title?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in frequency domain instead of time domain.

$$
G(s)=\frac{K(s+a)^2}{s} = \frac{Ks^2+2Kas+Ka^2}{s}
$$

according to the Laplace form of the PID controller
$$
G(s)=\frac{K_ds^2+K_ps+K_i}{s}
$$

so 
$$
K_d = K, K_p = 2Ka, K_i = Ka^2
$$

Answer (score 0):

The general PID form in Laplace domain is:
$$
G(s)=\frac{K_ds^2+K_ps+K_i}{s}
$$
The equation you've mentioned has a $Ks^3$ in the numerator. Hence, it cannot be transformed into PID form unless $K=0$, but that does not do you any good I guess.